# How does the weapon level up works in Darksiders

Tags: darksiders

In Darksiders you can level up your weapons. But how does this exactly work? Is it enough to just attack enemies with the weapons or is it necessary to kill them in order to gain weapon experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do to gain weapon experience is hitting enemies with them

Answer (score 0):

Chaos eater gains power per hit. Other weapons are per kill.